# How to test controller with Rspec - #show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a Batch model that `belongs_to` a User. User should only see their own Batches instances.

For the `index` action, here is what I did:

#### `Batch#index`

```
context "GET index" do

  it "should get only users batches" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:batch)
    batch = FactoryGirl.create(:batch)
    batch2 = FactoryGirl.create(:batch)            
    subject.current_user.batches << batch
    get "index"
    assigns(:batches).should == subject.current_user.batches
    assigns(:batches).should_not include(batch2) 
  end

end
```

For the `create` action, here is what I did:

#### `Batch#create`

```
context "POST create" do

  it "should save a users batch into current_user" do
    batch = subject.current_user.batches.build(name: 'bla')
    put :create, batch
    subject.current_user.batches.should include(batch)
  end

  it "should save a batch from other user into current_user" do
    batch = subject.current_user.batches.build(name: 'bla')
    batch2 = FactoryGirl.create(:batch)
    put :create, batch
    subject.current_user.batches.should_not include(batch2)
  end

end
```

However, I'm not sure how to test this behaviour in the `show` action. Here is what I'm doing:

#### `Batch#show`

```
context "GET show/:id" do

  it "should show batches from user" do
    batch_params = FactoryGirl.build(:batch)
    batch = subject.current_user.batches.create(batch_params)
    get :show, id: batch.id
    response.should redirect_to(batch)
  end

  it "should not show batches from other users" do
    batch = subject.current_user.batches.create(name: 'bla')
    batch2 = FactoryGirl.create(:batch)
    get :show, id: batch2.id
    response.should redirect_to(:batches)
  end

end
```

I'm getting the following failures:

```
Failures:

  1) BatchesController GET show/:id should not show batches from other users
     Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(:batches)
       Expected response to be a <:redirect>, but was <200>
     # ./spec/controllers/batches_controller_spec.rb:66:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) BatchesController GET show/:id should show batches from user
     Failure/Error: batch = subject.current_user.batches.create(batch_params)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<Batch:0x00000005d0ef80>
     # ./spec/controllers/batches_controller_spec.rb:58:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I test this behaviour of `view` action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first failure, "should not show batches from other users," looks like it might reflect an actual problem in your controller. Did you also test this in the browser to confirm the problem is in your test and not in the actual code?

On the other test, I'm not quite sure what the problem is exactly, but I would probably build the batch like this instead:

```
batch = FactoryGirl.create(:batch, user: subject.current_user)
```

Give that a try and see if it doesn't resolve it.

Comment: What's with the subject.current_user? what is subject?

Comment: subject is an instance of the class specified in the describe block, in this case an instance of the controller being spec'd. It's provided by rspec; see https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-14/docs/subject.

Answer (score 6):

```
get :show, id: batch.id
```

will not redirect it will render show, hence the response code 200, may be you can check

```
response.should render_template :show
```